# Optimization of React components with a children property?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

Good day!

When you create layout components faced the following problem - if the component layout accepts child components as children, and shouldComponentUpdate method is invoked every time the current and new props.children are not equal to each other (even when in fact these children are the same).

[Sample code on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/m3oxy88rpy)

Part of code here:

```js
class Layout extends React.Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate(newProps) {
    console.log(
      `%c COL SHOULD RENDER ${newProps.children === this.props.children}`,
      "color: green;"
    );
    return true;
  }

  render() {
    console.log('render');
    return (
      <div className="Layout">
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Input = props =>
  <div>
    {props.value}
  </div>;

const Page = () =>
  <Layout>
    <Input value="foo" />
    <Input value="bar" />
  </Layout>;

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      styles: {
        fontFamily: "sans-serif",
        textAlign: "center",
        color: "black"
      }
    };

    this.changeStylesColor = this.changeStylesColor.bind(this);
  }

  changeStylesColor() {
    this.setState({
      styles: {
        fontFamily: "sans-serif",
        textAlign: "center",
        color: "red"
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={this.state.styles}>
        <h2>
          Start editing to see some magic happen {"\u2728"}
        </h2>
        <Page />
        <button onClick={this.changeStylesColor}>Change color</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

When you click on the button "Change color" we are changing the state of the main App component, it causes a redraw of the Layout component, whose children have not changed.

For some reason, children are not always equal to each other, and how you can avoid these simple repaint of a static component, in addition to implementing your shouldComponentUpdate (not useful when a large number of incoming properties)?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. To get more answers please try to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Especially good if you can inline the code inside the question

Comment: I don't think what you say is true. The dom stays as it is and only the style is changed. There is no re-render of the children components.

Comment: @bluehipy but Layout Render method invoked every time, i add a log into this function.

Comment: That is normal since you are changing the state.

Comment: @bluehipy does it mean, that parent render invoke all childrens render, and it is not update a real DOM every time?

Comment: You can optimize the render call if you like by comparing the states but the comparison itself might be tricky.

Comment: @bluehipy okay, i understand about optimization.
But i'm right about Parent.render() call Children.render() , in usual case?

Comment: yes, but I think it is ok to have a chain of render call from parent to children.